# setTimeout, JavaScript, no effect

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I need to animate something, but my statement has no effect. My code:

```
var movei=function(img){
     img.setAttribute("src", "blank.png");
}

var comp=function() {
    ...    
    for(var k=0; k<i; k++) {
        var img=document.getElementById(id(k,col));
        img.setAttribute("src", "circ1.png");
        timer=setTimeout(movei(img),1000);
        ...
    }
}
```

I read another questions about `setTimeout` (`setInterval`) but I couldn`t find an answer.

Comment: `movei()` ***executes*** the function immediately. To pass a callback, don't *call* it: `setTimeout(movei, 1000)`.

Comment: You can add anonymous function and there call `movei(img)`

Comment: @DnisterLark I tried this,but the result is,as if I never used setTimeout

Comment: Do you realize once you fix your bug, all the images will be called exactly at one second?

Comment: try this: `timer=setTimeout(movei.bind(null,img),1000)` or `timer=setTimeout(function(){movei(img)},1000)`

Comment: @Rajesh `movei.bind(this, img)`

Answer (score 0):

try `timer=setTimeout(function(){movei(img);},1000);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to animate individual elements, you should use recursion instead of loops.

Following code depicts the same:

```js
var count = 0;

function getId(count) {
  return "div_" + count;
}

function initTimer() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    count++;
    var _id = getId(count);
    var _el = document.getElementById(_id);
    show(_el);
    if (count < 7)
      initTimer();
  }, 1000);
}

function show(el) {
  el.style.display = "block";
}

initTimer();
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="div_1">1</div>
<div id="div_2">2</div>
<div id="div_3">3</div>
<div id="div_4">4</div>
<div id="div_5">5</div>
<div id="div_6">6</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

As @deceze has also written, you need to change the call to setTimeout so that you do not call the movei function, but rather pass the function 'name'. Then you would of cause have to change the behavior the function movei so it either gets a simple string name of the image or can lookup the image itself.

```
timer=setTimeout(movei,1000);
```

or (in the not recommented way)

```
timer=setTimeout("movei(\"imgName\")",1000);
```

Comment: Please don't suggest passing callbacks as strings.

Comment: And the string method would fail in this case anyway

Comment: @deceze, can you elaborate a little on the why I shouldn't mention the callbacks as strings? I wouldn't either use it as my first choice, but it could solve a problem in some cases?

Comment: Whatever you can do with a string, you can also do with passing the function object directly. In this case either `movei.bind(null, imgName)` or `function () { movei(imgName); }`. Strings are eval'd in the global scope, which needlessly adds scoping issues and overhead.

Comment: Thanks, @deceze, I like the `function () { movei(imgName); }` way.I'll stick that into the toolbox ;-)